# How would you save the state of html table that allows you to toggle cell background color?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an HTML table below that allows users to click on a cell and toggle its background color. How can I save the state of the table and the toggled cells? So when the user revisits the page at another session, the same cells are highlighted.

```js
$(function () {
            $('td').click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('green');
            });
        });
```

```css
        .green {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>row1 col1</td>
            <td>row1 col2</td>
            <td>row1 col3</td>
            <td>row1 col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 col1</td>
            <td>row2 col2</td>
            <td>row2 col3</td>
            <td>row2 col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 col1</td>
            <td>row3 col2</td>
            <td>row3 col3</td>
            <td>row3 col4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row4 col1</td>
            <td>row4 col2</td>
            <td>row4 col3</td>
            <td>row4 col4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Local storage, session storage, cookie, server memory, external cache, database, file, registry, and more. Which would you like to use and what have you attempted?

Comment: I don't know what I would save though or how to save the state (not where to save the state, now since you shared those)

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, it might be helpful to save which rows are selected. _How_ you're going to save the value depends on _where_ you're going to save it.

Comment: and then how about what cells were previously highlighted

Comment: @Rod: When the page loads, what information would you require in order to restore it to its previous state?  That's the data you would save.  It could be a list of identifiers of which cells actively have the `green` class, perhaps by the index of rows/cells.  It could be a 2D array of rows/cells.  It could be the raw HTML of the entire table.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage`. My example is hardcoded, but I hope you get the point.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="my-button">Red background</button>

    <script>
      document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', saveColor);

      function saveColor() {
        localStorage.setItem('backgroundColor', 'Red');
        var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('backgroundColor');
        console.log(storedValue);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```